# jQuery removing numbers after the point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like my result to show the whole number as 1500, not 1500.00. I tried round () and toFixed () but it doesn't change my result and it doesn't round. Where do I go wrong?

```js
    var applying_credit_final = "applying_credit";
    
    var applying_credit = thisPointer.entity['applying_credit'];

    applying_credit_final = parseFloat(applying_credit_final);
    applying_credit = parseFloat(applying_credit);
        
            
    if (!isNaN(applying_credit_final) && !isNaN(applying_credit)) {
        var resultUNi = Number((applying_credit / 1000).toFixed())
        var numeralValUni = numeral(resultUNi)._value;
        numeralValUnit.toFixed()
```

My source
https://jsfiddle.net/Palucci92/jueL50hb/4/

Comment: your jsfiddle is not working, aka we can't help you then. Look at the console errors

Comment: It's hard to understand what your code is attempting to do, eg `var final="applying_credit"; final=parseFloat(final);`

Comment: Outputting as a *number*  `var x = 1500.00; console.log(x)` will not show the `.00`.  `toFixed(d)` will convert to a string with `d` decimals, so `var x = 1500.00; console.log(x.toFixed(0))` will not show the .00.  If you're getting `1500.00` then you're outputting a formatted *string*, likely in your un-provided `numeral` function.

Comment: Please reduce your code to include *only* the relevant code and *all* of the relevant code so that the code *reproduces* the issue in the question.  See [mcve].

Comment: Try .toFixed(0) which i had to to do once.  This removes the decimals but wont round your number. You could also try Math.ceil(numeralValUnit) which will jump to the next full number if the decimal over .00 eg 9.01 will become 10

Answer (score 0):

To remove excessive decimals you need to specify the number of digits to keep as parameter on toFixed:

```
var resultUNi = Number((applying_credit / 1000).toFixed(0))
```

Notice 0 as parameter in `toFixed(0)` resulting in an integer. You can also leave the parameter out if its zero because it defaults to it.

Comment: "to round" ... `toFixed` - round and fixed are different concepts -  `(val/1000).toFixed() ` will *not* "round" the value.

Comment: Note that `.toFixed()` is the same as `.toFixed(0)` - no need to specify 0 as a fix for it not being specified.